# Mirror browser back button behavior on UI back button

Tags: javascript

TLDR: I would like to detect when the browser back button is disabled.

My website has a back button in the UI. For the most part it works exactly like the browser's back button, accomplished by simply using the browser's history.back() functionality.  However, when a user clicks a shared link in an email, if the back end does a redirection, it appears that the browser is smart enough to show a disabled back button, but our javascript call to history.back() sends back to the original URL, which then does the forwarding again.

My idea is to detect when the browser back button is disabled, and also disable the one in our UI, but my search thus far hasn't been fruitful.

History.length is not 0, and I also looked into using history.referrer, but from what I've read, that solution isn't always reliable either.

I'm open to completely rethinking this problem, however, removing the back button from the web UI is out of my control.

Comment: Use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` to store a value to test against. But, really... I'm pretty sure your coding practices aren't any good.

Comment: its a huge project with hundreds of developers... I can't even say I understand everything that's going on. There is angular routing, lots of react, and dozens of services involved. I don't doubt for a second that there is something funky involved, I just don't really know where to start sniffing. Do you have a hunch? @StackSlave

Comment: I'm the wrong guy to ask. I'd gut the entire project until I was sure of perfection.